# VS 2013: curly braces size mismatch

Tags: visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

I have got a problem with my Visual Studio 2013:

My curly braces have different sizes.

If I write some code in the same line they change the size to match my editor font size.

Is there a config section where I can disable this behavior?

[image: The same size?]

Comment: This problem also happens in VS 2012 and VS 2015 because of the Productivity Power Tools.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, after a while looking for a solution I found that the problem was an extension: VS Productivity Power Tools 2013: Syntactic Line Compression.

1. Click "Tools" -> "Options"
2. Choose "Productivity Power Tools" in the Options window
3. Toggle "Syntactic Line Compression" to "Off"

Hope this helps.
PS: This solution works with VS 2015 and VS 2017 too.

Comment: Works with VS 2019 as well. Thank you! It was so painful to look at code in VS before.

Answer (score 3):

Also the same in VS 2019 with Productivity Power Tools.

Tools/Options/Productivity Power Tools:
(Disable Syntactic Line Compression as below)

[image]