# Curly braces decrease scale on new line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, code-formatting, curly-braces

In visual studio when using curly braces after loops or if or any other time they become very little in scale and I don't like it. This is happening after installing resharper but I have already uninstalled it, Does anyone encountered something like this before? here is the picture below[image]

This braces looks really miserable and awful and I would be pleased if someone give me a good suggestion, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have other plugins / extensions installed?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708720/vs-2013-curly-braces-size-mismatch ?